# How to find who claimed a task in Process Portal?

Tags: ibm-bpm

We have a task that was created in IBM BPM and assigned to a Group.
In case someone from my Group has claimed it, how do I find which user of the group claimed the task?

Thanks,
Bharath

Answer (score 0):

You may use Process Inspector application at /ProcessInspector with a user with administrative privileges.

You may search for and locate your process instance, and then locate the task you're interested in at details panel at the right-hand side. If the task is not yet claimed, you'll see the group name here, or if it's claimed by someone in that group you'll see that user's name.

[image: ProcessInspector]

Answer (score 0):

You can get this info from the REST APIs. If you know the Process ID you can use the task summary REST API: http://host_name:port_number/rest/bpm/wle/v1/process/<process_id>/taskSummary/

Or if you know the Task ID you can use the Task Details REST API: http://host_name:port_number/rest/bpm/wle/v1/task/<task_id>?parts=all

You can test using the IBM BPM REST Test Tool: http://host_name:port_number/bpmrest-ui